# Which tense should be used after "once"?

Tags: grammar, tense, present-participles

Which of the following is correct?

- I will update you *once I reached* my home.
- I will update you *once I reach* my home.
- I will update you *after I reaching* my home.

Comment: *Reach* or *have reached*. But in the US we'd be more likely to say *once I **get** home*. In this context, the place where I live is *home*; ***my** home* is the building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the three samples you have provided, the middle one is correct:

> I will update you once I reach my home.

The first one is wrong because you are mentioning there that you'll do something in the future **after** you do something in past(which of course doesn't make sense).

Same situation arises in the third one.

Again, as @StoneyB mentions:

> **get** is a much better choice here.

Answer (score 4):

The last one is wrong, since you don't say "I reaching my home"; it would be "I am reaching my home." but you don't say "I will update you after I am reaching my home."

The correct one is "I will update you once I reach my home." I would rather say "once I arrive home," but I think that is a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, it is actually possible to do things in the future after having done some in the past (what?!?):

*We use once as a conjunction meaning ‘as soon as’ or ‘after’:*

*Once I’ve picked Megan up, I’ll call you.*

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/once